# Why will this margin offset not work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a margin offset in css, here is the html for it:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  /*border: solid black 1px;*/
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
}

.column.one-half {
  width: 50%;
}

.column.one-fourth {
  width: 25%;
}

.column.one-eighth {
  width: 12.5%;
}

.offset-one-fourth {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.offset-half {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half">1/2</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-eighth">1/8</div>
    <div class="column one-eighth">1/8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half offset-half"></div>
    <div class="column one-half">1/2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half offset-one-fourth"></div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what happens when I run it :

[image: Offset attempt]
I have tried messing with the margins, the width percentages, the order of the html but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You've shown us what happens. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry, I was expecting the offset to appear in order, not at the end of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using your own classes incorrectly!

There’s no need to insert an extra element to apply the offset - just add the offset class to the first element *after* the offset.

*The CSS below is the same as in the question, just minified to save space.*

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}.container{margin:0 auto;width:80%}.row{width:100%;margin:10px}.row:after{content:"";display:table;clear:both}.column{float:left;background-color:grey}.column.one-half{width:50%}.column.one-fourth{width:25%}.column.one-eighth{width:12.5%}.offset-one-fourth{margin-left:25%}.offset-half{margin-left:50%}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half">1/2</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-eighth">1/8</div>
    <div class="column one-eighth">1/8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-half offset-half">1/2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column one-fourth offset-one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
    <div class="column one-fourth">1/4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```